# In Python Tkinter can I press a button to run any exe file?

Tags: python, button, tkinter, exe

I have been studying on using Tkinter to open exe files from the one Tkinter software. My end product was a Windows 7 exe file that ran all the exe files from the one Tkinter software that was converted to exe file.

I will explain my code going from top to bottom 
This is my Tkinter Template of sorts

```
from Tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import os
class App:
def __init__(self, master):
    self.frame = Frame(master)
```

I added a image to give users information How to use the software

```
    img = Image.open("data.gif")
    intro = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
    right = Label(None, image=intro)
    right.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=4)
    right.image=intro
```

then I added Buttons to the grid, calling every button self.b realy confused people here at stack overflow. you will read the comments soon.

```
    self.b = Button(self.frame, bg="red", fg="white", font=("Helvetica", 14), text = ' \n confilextracter \n ', command = self.openFile1)
    self.b.grid(row = 1, column=0)
    self.b = Button(self.frame, bg="red", fg="white", font=("Helvetica", 14), text = ' \n confileditor \n ', command = self.openFile2)
    self.b.grid(row = 1, column=1)
    self.b = Button(self.frame, bg="red", fg="white", font=("Helvetica", 14), text = ' \n confilerehasher \n ', command = self.openFile3)
    self.b.grid(row = 1, column=2)
    self.b = Button(self.frame, bg="red", fg="white", font=("Helvetica", 14), text = ' \n Turn off the Shed \n ', command = self.openFile4)
    self.b.grid(row = 1, column=3)
    self.frame.grid()
```

Next I had to give the buttons jobs to carry out, renaming exe files realy confused people here at stack overflow. sorry about that.

```
def openFile1(self):
    os.startfile("confilextracter.exe")
def openFile2(self):
    os.startfile("confileditor.exe")
def openFile3(self):
    os.startfile("confilerehasher.exe")
```

I realy wanted the last button code corrected witch I found the answer myself because everyone else was busy sorting out all the other parts of this code as you will see soon enough. at this point in time this next button has errors in it.

```
def openFile4(self):
    self.b.configure(command = self.b.destroy)
```

Then I closed the file

```
root = Tk()
app = App(root)
mainloop()
```

Comment: Look at the [`subprocess`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) module to learn how to create other processes from Python.

Comment: You can't name them all self.b; that will just have one button (the last one assigned).

Comment: @F3AR3DLEGEND I placed each self.b on a diferent column making colnes of it's self with different text on them, I also changed the commands to diferent def's producing diferent outcomes

Answer (score 2):

Using the `os` module:

```
from Tkinter import *
import os

class App:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.frame = Frame(master)
        self.b = Button(self.frame, text = 'Open', command = self.openFile)
        self.b.grid(row = 1)
        self.frame.grid()
    def openFile(self):
        os.startfile(_filepath_)

root = Tk()
app = App(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I tryed using from Tkinter import *
import os

class App:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.frame = Frame(master)
        self.b = Button(self.frame, text = 'Open', command = self.openFile)
        self.b.grid(row = 1)
        self.frame.grid()
    def openFile(self):
        os.startfile(Xplorer.exe)

root = Tk()
app = App(root)
root.mainloop()

Comment: @KenRoberts You need to provide a full filepath, like 'D:\Windows\User\my_file.exe'. Also, it has to be a string.

Comment: Code works now that I put it into a string.  def openFile(self):
        os.startfile("Xplorer.exe")

Comment: @KenRoberts: Isn't "Xplorer.exe" a virus?

Comment: @martineau I been changing filenames for better coding understanding after all the end user don't care what the files are named.

Comment: @KenRoberts: F3AR3DLEGEND's point was that the .exe file name you use has to be able to be found by the OS. If the path to its folder hasn't been added to the system's `PATH` environment variable, then the full path will have to be provided in the argument given to `os.startfile()`.

Comment: @martineau the softare works compleaty now. It's all ready published on the internet for download. I use short address and not full path and everything works.

Comment: @KenRoberts Are you publishing a virus on the internet? Besides, it won't work when you run a program and try to open a filename; it only looks for that in the local directory of the program. You need a filepath for it to work from any location.

Comment: @F3AR3DLEGEND I'm Banned from Stackoverflow they put a stop to me Posting anymore Questions. Personaly I'm sick of people thinking Your out to break the law just because you just put your foot into the door of publishing programing. You ask if I published virus if I paid copywrite on this product I would take you to court over your statment and Win.

Comment: I am very sure flaming is breaking the rules of TOS in any forum.

Comment: @KenRoberts That was not flaming; that was me asking whether or not you published a virus on the Internet, because martineau said it is, and a simple Google search shows that it is.

Comment: @F3AR3DLEGEND the old saying is don't belive every thing you read. All my products are scanned with https://www.virustotal.com/en/ my other forum hosts demand I use one all the time. sack overflow dosen't demand it but I have to so, so I can use my other forum Hosts.

Answer (score 1):

**This is what I did to make things work,**
I took f3ar3dlegend example code (scroll up) and started working on it as it worked pretty good.
Lets talk about the top lines of code and work our way down for a full breakdown.

```
from Tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import os
```

from Tkinter import, this tells pyhton to load the GUI drivers. from PIL import Image, ImageTK tell Python to load Pyhton image library so we can use color photos. import os this to my understanding loads drivers so Python can run outside programs from a python app calling them into action.

The first thing I did was to add a image to f3ar3dlegend's code to give my users a information page with this code,

```
    class App:
    def __init__(self, master):

    self.frame = Frame(master)
    img = Image.open("data.gif")
    intro = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
    right = Label(None, image=intro)
    right.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=4)
    right.image=intro
```

One line of code was stoping me image from apearing for a good 24 hours was just simply missing code

```
    right.image=intro
```

This line of code stops your image being garbage collected (what ever that means) I just know I added it and my photos should up when put inside a def.

The Next thing I put a lot of work into was Button formating, you know width size color Font. Figgering out to use self.frame was pure guesswork I just kept trying ideas until one of my trys worked. I also have this whole thing on a Python Tkinter Grid so the image went on row 0 and column spaned 4 or 5 colums to make way for more buttons. These Buttons all went on row 1 not row 0. I found I could call all the buttons self.b as long as the command was to a different def the code was error free.

```
    self.b = Button(self.frame, bg="darkred", width=18, fg="white", font=("Arial", 14), text = ' \n confilextracter \n ', command = self.openFile1)
    self.b.grid(row = 1, column=0)
    self.b = Button(self.frame, bg="red", width=17, fg="white", font=("Arial", 14), text = ' \n confileditor \n ', command = self.openFile2)
    self.b.grid(row = 1, column=1)
```

The next thing I did was def's as buttons don't work without these. What made stock overflow think I was uploading a virus was that I changed the programe names to make me understand my programing better.

```
    def openFile1(self):
    os.startfile("confilextracter.exe")
    def openFile2(self):
    os.startfile("confileditor.exe")
```

It works like this. openFile1 is a Button callout. You press the button and it gives out a callout and the matching def obeys the anser to the call. os.startfile is a new term to me but it simply means operating system start file. ("confileditor.exe") is saying the string name of the file you need is between (" ") put the two together and the file runs in its own window.
The last bit of this software i peaced together and then said I can do more with this. I started off using f3ar3dlegend example code again.

```
   root = Tk()
   app = App(root)
   mainloop()
```

This basicly turns everything off so Python knows it's time to display stuff and mainloop tells Tkinter to wait for me to do stuff. Problem was the software was opening sometime half on the page and at other times anywhere on the screen so I added this code to put the software at the top left of the screen.

```
   app = App(root)
   root.geometry('+0+0')
   mainloop()
```

One last thing I did was to get a button to Exit the software at the click of a button after trying 5 or 6 trys I got Tkinter to destroy the software window with the push of a button. the code is.

```
   self.b = Button(self.frame, bg="red", width=18, fg="white", font=   ("Arial", 14), text = ' \n Turn off the Shed \n ', command = self.openFile4)
   self.b.grid(row = 1, column=3)
   def openFile4(self):
   root.destroy()
```

I have seen counless examples on stack overflow of people using root.destory wrongy, is it any wonder I tinkered with it for 1 hour to get it just right.
One very important lesson I did learn about putting programs online so people can download them is You need to contact Customber support of your host and Demand a link to there TOS terms of service because if you don't understand TOS your probably breaking international laws to do with publishing. Thank you.

Comment: Ken, you shouldn't post just a working solution as an answer on this site. The answer section is strictly for answers. However, if you think your working code is the best answer, please edit yor answer to include a few paragraphs about what you did. Otherwise, people who have the same problem as you probably won't be able to learn anything from just the code.

Comment: @BryanOakley I would like to remind you that I am banned from posting "The answer section is strictly for answers." so I posted it here instead. If I can't click, Add a Answer Button to my own thread then why the hell did Sack Overflow add the buitton there in the first place if people using it would only get into trouble? Sure I will do as you ask, "include a few paragraphs about what you did" as you have gave me permision to do so. cya

Comment: you don't need my permission to write a useful answer, but you have a responsibility to try and make your answers useful. This site is for questions and answers, not threaded discussions. Don't be so defensive; just learn the rules for this site and stick to them.

Comment: @BryanOakley how do I talk with you in private away from Threads? As of now when I goto Ask a question I keep getting this answer.  Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions from this account. See http://goo.gl/C1Kwu to learn more. Is the damage permanent? Tell me in private if your willing to help ok. And How do I read private messages? cya

Comment: follow the link in that message and read _everything_; that will answer your questions about being banned.